# New object instance not being recognized- Java

Tags: java, instances

I am having trouble getting a random generator instance from being recognized as an object and it won't allow for use within another .class file. The base code for the random integer generator is this:

```
package RandomInstanceGenerator;
import java.util.Random;

/** Generate 10 random integers in the range 0..99. */
public final class RandomInteger {

  public static final void main(String... aArgs){
    log("Generating 10 random integers in range 0..99.");

    //note a single Random object is reused here
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
      int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
      log("Generated : " + randomInt);
    }

    log("Done.");
  }

  private static void log(String aMessage){
    System.out.println(aMessage);
  }
}
```

I am trying to have the code below run what is above as a new instance. I have tried several methods that were apparent to me from other learnings, but they have failed me and so I request the knowledge of others for help in understanding. I say that in understanding that i literally copied and pasted the base code from another source that has it run as it's own little .class. Here is the code that tries to create a new instance:

```
package RandomInstanceGenerator;
import java.util.Random;
class Inst {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    RandomInteger rig=new RandomInteger();
    rig.main(args);
  }
}
```

I am certain both need editing, hope I can fix this out so it works for me.

List of attempted changes:

1) Tried importing RandomInteger.class. The error given back says it cannot find symbol "Random Integer".

I used the code `import RandomInstanceGenerator.RandomInteger;`.

2) Working on the next attempt later..

Comment: If you're seeing an error and need our help, you need to print the exact and full error text. Else you're forcing us to guess.

Comment: Note that you're trying to call a static method on an instance and not on the class. This can be done but is not a good practice. More important, I think that you don't want your RandomInteger class to have a main method, or any static methods, and in fact I'm willing to wager money on this.

Comment: It is saying it cannot find the symbols "RandomInteger" when I try to create a new instance.

Comment: You will have to try any changes and see if it works or not. We are a poor substitute for your Java compiler and JVM.

Comment: Then that isn't going to help then, so nevermind on that small question.. Hm. I will work some more and edit my post with more details if i cannot find a way to get it to work. thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to show us a specific set of headers (package/import/class lines) and the specific (copy/paste) error generated, plus describe your directory structure and give us the exact javac command line you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Java executes a program it looks for a `main` function; in this case in your second class. That class then instantiates your first class (via `new RandomInteger()`). You then attempt to call into that first class's main method.

Note, though, that the method is labeled `static`. Static methods are executable only on the class, not on a specific instantiated object. If you were to use RandomInteger.main() you could expect a different result:

```
class Inst {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    RandomInteger.main(args);
  }
}
```

But note that this is equivalent to just running RandomInteger as it's own program. If, as you say, you want to run your program as a method on an object, this is what you want:

```
public final class RandomInteger {
  private Random randomGenerator = new Random(); //A single object can reuse this component

  //function prints out x random numbers between low and high
  //Note that your function should do ONE thing, therefore do not make it also interpret
  //your program arguments!
  public void logXRandomNumbers(int x, int low, int high){ 
    log("Generating " + x + " random integers in range " + low ".." + high);

    int range = high - low;
    //you really should do a sanity check here to ensure the range is valid.

    //note a single Random object is reused here
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= x; ++idx){
      int nextResult = this.randomGenerator.nextInt(range) + low;
      log("Generated : " + nextResult);
    }

    log("Done.");
  }

  //This function is probably overkill
  private static void log(String aMessage){
    System.out.println(aMessage);
  }
}
```

Now all you have to do is call this from your main function:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
  RandomInteger generator = new RandomInteger();
  generator.logXRandomNumbers(10, 0, 100);
}
```

As for your imports, both classes should have the same package. Lets say its `Generator` for simplicity:

```
package Generator;
```

Only your second class (the not very-well-named Inst) needs to import your generator/logging class:

```
import Generator.*;
```

or

```
import Generator.RandomInteger;
```

Be sure that both of these files are in the same directory named 'Generator' and that you are running `javac` from the directory above that.

Comment: It worked! I thank you for your effort in explanation to a less than understanding individual. Thanks. :)